# Program or Firefox plugin to automatically manipulate website HTML using specific rules?

Tags: windows, firefox, website, plugins

I have noticed dozens of times how tedious some websites are.

Therefore, I need a program, plugin for Firefox, or whatever that does the job - to be able to add some sort of checks to specific websites.

For example, the program could search for a regexp pattern, and then do an action according to it. For example if I find some language from the wikipedia page, I would like to move or copy it on top of that languages list. The action wouldn't necessarily have to be applied on the regexp it found: it could issue another regexp search, and if it's found, it would do the actions I want, such as delete a block of other piece of HTML, move it, or copy it to another location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Firefox add-on [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey).

Comment: Do you know how to use these scripts on userscripts.org ? currently i only got working the wikipedia script. I tried to install the phpBB scripts to hide some topics permanently, but i just fail. Tried to add the websites as `// @include http://some.web/site/forum/*` or without "*", and without slash etc. i tried both scripts: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/57924 and http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/119197 none seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

userscripts.org/scripts/show/119197 is working fine here.

Rather than adding

```
// @include http://example.com/site/forum/*
```

to the source code itself, try to just add the forums of your choosing in the options thing inside of greasemonkey.

1. Click on the dropdown arrow next to the greasemonkey toolbar button
2. Click on "manage user scripts..." which should open the Add-ons-Manager with the Greasemonkey-panel highlighted.
3. Find the script phpBB Thread Blocker and click on its "preferences" button.
4. The window named "Greasemonkey - Userscript-preferences" should open up.
5. Go to its tab "User preferences"
6. Click on the "Add" button
7. Paste your forum-page into the text area "Apply to these sites".

The added page(s) should have that syntax:

```
http://example.com/site/forum/*
```

Finally, click on the "OK" button and all should be done.

Note that pages added this way should not have the leading `// @include` which is meta-information, but only correct if script's sources were edited directly via an editor.
Other userscripts should work right doing so, but I didn't try that with this script.

[image: The image shows how a page looks like with the applied userscript.]

A click on a red X hides a thread, and there's an additional link at the bottom of the page. A click on "Edit Hidden Threads" shows them up in a list below the hidden threads-link, if one of them clicked, related thread is unhidden again. I think a page reload (F5) was necessary too.

Comment: somehow, i just fail. how should the page look when its enabled? i cant see any changes.

Comment: looks like it works only for some phpBB boards! also, how do i undo my hiding?